# Finding the lowest value of an item in a list of OrderedDict

Tags: python, dictionary, ordereddictionary

I have an OrderedDict that each key has more than one value.

```
list_of_dict = 
[OrderedDict([('time', 0.18), ('dist', 92.61), ('x', True)]), 
 OrderedDict([('time', 0.92), ('dist', 92.10), ('x', True)]),
 OrderedDict([('time', 1.45), ('dist', 92.79), ('x', False)])]
```

Need to return the dictionary with lowest time among all the orderededDict present in the list_of_dict.

Example - list_of_dict[0][time] is lowest among remaining dict, so need to return entire

```
OrderedDict([('time', 0.18), ('dist', 92.61), ('x', True)])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the `min()` function with `key` as a `lambda`.

```py
from collections import OrderedDict

list_of_dict = [
    OrderedDict([("time", 1.45), ("dist", 92.79), ("x", False)]),
    OrderedDict([("time", 0.18), ("dist", 92.61), ("x", True)]),
    OrderedDict([("time", 0.92), ("dist", 92.10), ("x", True)]),
]

print(min(list_of_dict, key=lambda x: x["time"]))
```

You can also use `itemgetter`, instead of a lambda.

```py
from collections import OrderedDict
from operator import itemgetter

list_of_dict = [
    OrderedDict([("time", 1.45), ("dist", 92.79), ("x", False)]),
    OrderedDict([("time", 0.18), ("dist", 92.61), ("x", True)]),
    OrderedDict([("time", 0.92), ("dist", 92.10), ("x", True)]),
]

print(min(list_of_dict, key=itemgetter("time")))
```

Comment: Duplicate answer as @rioV8

Answer (score 2):

use the `min()` function and define a `key` property function

```py
min(list_of_dict, key=lambda x: x['time'])
```